# int* value of a void* address

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

So, I was messing with pointers, and I've got confused with some things. First, let me start with a basic example which beahaves like expected:

```
void* h = new char[16] {}; //pointer to a array of char, 16 bytes, and initilizes with 0
int* o = (int*)h; //gets the adress of the first byte
*o = 16; //sets the value
std::cout << *(int*)h << std::endl; //Prints the memory value
std::cout << *o; //Prints the memory value
```

and It prints this:

```
16
16
```

But this one doesn't output what I think it would:

```
    int* o = (int*)h+1; //gets the adress of the second byte
    *o = 16; //sets the value
    std::cout << *(int*)h+1 << std::endl; //Prints the memory value
    std::cout << *o; //Prints the memory value
```

But it outputs:

```
1
16
```

Shouldn't the two numbers be 16?
As far as I know, by adding value to the pointer it increments the memory in bytes. So, is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: These are all aliasing violations and therefore cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Note: if you are ever using `void*` in C++ and it is not because some C API (that you cannot change) is forcing you to, then you are probably *doing it wrong*.

Comment: Try `*((int*)h+1)`, which is an equivallent of `*o`. `*(int*)h+1` resolves as `(*(int*)h)+1`. If the memory is, by accident, zeroed out, then it prints 1.

Comment: `(int*)h+1;` does NOT gets the adress of the second byte. Instead it gets the adress of the 5th byte. The `+1` does not increment the pointer by one it increments the pointer by four. This depends one type the pointer is pointing to. And since int has four bytes, the pointer is moved to the second integer, i.e. by four byte.

Comment: In c++ you should not use c style castings `(int*)`, it prevents the compiler from warning you about things you do wrong, and you can't express what casting you actually want to do. Use [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), [reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with precedence of operators. Of all the operators you are using the highest precedence is that of the cast to `(int*)`. So when you do `(int*)h+1` you are actually doing `((int*)h)+1`, and that is not the pointer to the second byte, but a pointer to the second *integer*, that is you are advancing `sizeof(int)` bytes.

Similarly with `*(int*)h+1` you are actually doing `(*(int*)h)+1`, that is you are reading the first integer (that would be `0`) and adding 1 to that integer (`0 + 1 = 1`). In this case you are not doing pointer arithmetic.

If you want to do proper pointer arithmentic you need a few parenthesis, but note that you cannot portably do pointer arithmentic with `void *`: use instead `char *`